# The dropdown menu is getting open and closed both simultaneously after clicking the nav link

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

The dropdown menu is getting open and closed both simultaneously after clicking the nav link.
I am trying to make a dropdown menu and it is getting closed by itself:

When I am trying to click on the dropdown, it is closing by itself, and I am not able to catch the problem.
The HTML, CSS and JavaScript code are as follows:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSm9O.gif)

```js
let dropdownLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-linkdrp");
let drpdwnMenu = document.querySelector(".drpdwn-menu");

function drpdwnMenuFunc() {
  drpdwnMenu.classList.toggle("drpdwn-menu-active");
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2vw;
}

.nav-items {
  list-style: none;
}

.drpdwn {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.4vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drpdwn-menu {
  display: none;
}

.drpdwn-menu-active {
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 10vw;
  height: auto;
  border: solid black 3px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.drpdwn-item {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1vh 2vw 1vh 2vw;
}

.drpdwn-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
}

.nav-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="" class="nav-links">HOME</a></li>
  <li onclick="drpdwnMenuFunc()" class="nav-items drpdwn">
    <a href="" class="nav-links nav-linkdrp">LEARN</a>
    <i class="ri-arrow-down-s-fill"></i>
    <ul class="drpdwn-menu">
      <li class="drpdwn-item"><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li class="drpdwn-item"><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
      <li class="drpdwn-item"><a href="">BLOGS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-items drpdwn">
    <a href="" class="nav-links">DISCOVER</a>
    <i class="ri-arrow-down-s-fill"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="" class="nav-links">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

I was expecting a good dropdown.

Comment: You neglected to suppress the default action of the click event, so this makes the page reload (because you effectively clicked on `<a href="">`, and than empty href simply makes the link point to the current page.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is so simple & hidden.

You have used an anchor tag that reloads the page on click.

Just replace 
`<a href="" class="nav-links nav-linkdrp">LEARN</a>` 
with 
`<span class="nav-links nav-linkdrp">LEARN</span>`

And along with this, I checked your CSS code. In your CSS code, add `position: relative;` in your `.drpdwn` selector.

```
.drpdwn {
            display: flex;
            gap: 0.4vw;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: relative;
        }
```